# Why doesn't this makefile implicit rule work?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a `Makefile`, and am trying to make this specific set of variables and implicit rules work

```
pcode-LINKDEPS := pasv5-database pasv5-log pasv5-utils
%/node_modules: $(%-LINKDEPS)
    cd $*; npm install; for link in $^ ; do npm link $$link ; done
pasv5-database:
    cd libs/database; npm link
```

I can remove directory `pcode/node_modules` and run `make -d` and I can see that it picks up the pattern rule `%/node_modules` and does the basic install but the `$^` expansion is empty and so the link doesn't happen and the pre-requisite target pasv5-database never gets run .  Does this mean that I can't put `%` inside the pre-requisite expansion, and if so what approach can I take to effectively get `pcode-LINKDEPS` selected for the list of prerequisites, so the target `pasv5-database` gets run?

Or am I making some other fundamental mistake?

pasv5-database (and the other elements of pcode-LINKDEPS) are all defined in `.PHONY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that `$(%-LINKDEPS)` is expanded before the rule is matched to the target you're trying to build. And since you have no variable called `%-LINKDEPS`, it expands to nothing.

Try [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%/node_modules: $$(%-LINKDEPS)
    ...
```

Comment: Perfect.  I actually had quite a few of these which weren't working, but now it does exactly what I want.